# What do you call a dependency that "leaks" to client code? What do you call one that doesn't?

Tags: terminology, dependencies

Let's say you have a library `StuffDoer` which calls an external library `MagicWizard` to do its stuff. Then you add a reference to `StuffDoer` in `UsefulApp`.

In some scenarios, referencing `StuffDoer` requires `UsefulApp` to reference `MagicWizard` directly (it "leaks"), while in some scenarios, it does not. I think in .NET it depends on whether or not the public API of `StuffDoer` makes reference to `MagicWizard`'s types, or if they are only referenced in private code?

So my question is, what do you call the reference in these scenarios?

I've been thinking some good names for the type of reference that "leaks" might be "transitive reference" or "external reference". And some good names for the type of reference that doesn't "leak" might be "nontransitive reference" or "internal reference".

Are there established terms to describe these types of references? I'd like to be on the same page as everyone else, of course!

Comment: [This seems relevant](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) but I'm not sure if the term '(non-)leaky abstractions' fits what you are looking for.

Comment: I thin you would say the reference "exposes its internals"

Comment: Not _exactly_ what you're asking for, but the terms _leaky abstration_ and _encapsulation_ are relevant to this kind of discussion.

Answer (score 2):

The term of ***[indirect dependency](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/indirect-dependency)***  may be used to accurately describe this kind of dependencies. It opposes to [*direct dependency*](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/ood/understanding-dependencies.html#directindirect).

Sometimes it’s called ***chained dependency***. However, the term is more ambiguous, since there can be a chain without necessary having a leak.

Comment: "Indirect dependency" also refers more generally to your dependencies' dependencies (and further out), regardless of whether or not they leak.

Comment: @AlexReinking exactly!  “leak” suggests something negative and undesired. “indirect” is completely neutral. It may create an undesired coupling, but on the other side in some cases, it can be an unavoidable consequence of componentization (as suggested in the detailed description of the facade in GoF).

Answer (score 0):

If you tried to run `UsefulApp` without having installed `MagicWizard.dll` in its folder (or probing path or GAC), it wouldn't work. Therefore it is called a "dependency." You have to have it. Whether or not it is referenced, you still have to have it.

The only time you'd need to set a reference is if you wanted to use its types, which can happen if `StuffDoer` uses its types in its public interface. But `UsefulApp` might also use its types directly. In either case, `MagicWizard.dll` would then become a "referenced assembly."

If you have a dependency and you don't set a reference to it, it is an "unreferenced dependency."

Answer (score -1):

I would probably call the "leaky" dependencies *exposed* and the "non-leaky" ones *internal* or *private*. I don't think there's any standardised terminology for this distinction yet.